# Hilt Singleton injection with Java

Tags: java, android, dagger-hilt

Here is my module:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent.class)
public class BleRepositoryModule {
    @Provides
    public static BleRepository providesPedalRepository(@ApplicationContext Context context) {
        return new BleRepository(context);
    }
}
```

This is the class that I want to be injected as a singleton, that is created by the module

```
@Singleton
public class BleRepository {
    @Inject
    public BleRepository(@ActivityContext Context context) {
    }
}
```

I am injecting this singleton in viewmodels such as this:

```
@HiltViewModel
public class PedalViewModel extends AbstractViewModel {
    @Inject
    public PedalViewModel(BleRepository bleRepository) {
        super();
    }
}
```

However, I see the constructor is called every time it is injected, so it's not acting like a singleton

Comment: Change `@ActivityContext` to `@ApplicationContext` .. And Add `@Singleton` annotation to `providesPedalRepository` method   ..

Comment: Do I need @Singleton to the BleRepository class definition?

Comment: this is a wrong design. why do you need context in repository? can you pls explain ur use case. may be this needs a redesign.

Comment: @rakeshkashyap the context is needed for some methods required for BLE